# Count number of members at the end of each year

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following fields: `user_id`, `join_date`, `leave_date`.
Note: There are some years that have no joiners or leavers, and if they are still a member then the leave_date is NULL.

I am trying to retrieve the total number of members at the end of each calendar year from 2010 to today.

I have tried to write this for the most recent year only using the following code:

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id) 
FROM memberships 
WHERE join_date < '2021-12-31' AND leave_date is null
```

Comment: please try  where join_date < '20211231' and leave_date is null

Comment: [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) dates are formatted `'YYYY-MM-DD'`; don't use regional bespoke encoding for dates.

Comment: Reverse `31/12/2021`  by  `2021/12/31`

Comment: @atika - ISO-8601 states that you should be using `-` not `/`

Comment: Thank you all for your comments - that fixes my query for one year. The main part of the query which is how to get the total number of members at the end of each calendar year from 2010 to today is still unresolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With Years 
As
(
    Select min(year(join_date)) as [Year]
    From members
    Union All
    Select Y.[Year] + 1
    From Years Y
    Where Y.[Year] + 1 <= Year(GetDate()) 
)
Select [Year], 
    COUNT(*) As [End Year Member Count]
From Years
    Left Join members On [Year] Between Year(members.join_date) 
        And (Year(IsNull(leave_date, getdate() + 365)) - 1)
    Group By [Year]
```

Comment: This is tremendous thank you - I now just need to work out how to apply it to my data where there is another column called team and people can be members of more than one team :( .... SO if they are a member of 3 teams they are only counted once per year, not three times. But this is a great solution thank you

Comment: Then replace `Left Join members` with a subquery that returns a single record per member. Something like `Left Join (Select Distinct user_id, min(join_date) as earliest_join_date, max(leave_date) as final_join_date From members) As Members`. Keep in mind that if there are gaps in membership, it needs a little more tweaking. Post the some sample data and I'll try to suggest something.

Comment: That is incredibly interesting thank you.

Comment: That is incredibly interesting thank you. I had been working on doing something like this: 

select '2020' as 'Year', count(user_id) as 'Members'
from (select distinct user_id from memberships where ((join_date<='2020-12-31' and leave_date is null) OR (join_date<= '2020-12-31' AND leave_date>'2020-12-31')

UNION 
select '2019' as 'Year', count(user_id) as 'Members'
from (select distinct user_id from memberships where ((join_date<='2019-12-31' and leave_date is null) OR (join_date<= '2019-12-31' AND leave_date>'2019-12-31')

etc etc

Not pretty!

Answer (score 0):

yeah, how about a query like below

```
; with date_cte as 
(
select cast('2010-12-31' as date) as lastdate, cast('2010-01-01' as date) as prev_lastdate
union all
select dateadd(YY,1,lastdate) as lastdate, dateadd(YY,1,prev_lastdate) as prev_lastdate
from date_cte where  dateadd(YY,1,lastdate) <getutcdate()
)


select 
    lastdate,count(user_id) as count_members
from memberships 
right join date_cte
on  join_date  <= lastdate 
    and (leave_date is null or leave_date >lastdate)
group by lastdate
```

I ran tests against this data

```
drop table if exists memberships ;
create table memberships (user_id int , join_date date, leave_date date) ;
insert into memberships values
(1,'2009-01-01','2015-09-08'),
(2,'2009-01-01','2016-09-08'),
(3,'2012-01-01','2013-09-08'),
(4,'2013-01-01','2013-07-08'),
(5,'2017-01-01',NULL);
select * from memberships
```

results are:

```
lastdate    count_members

2010-12-31  2
2011-12-31  2
2012-12-31  3
2013-12-31  2
2014-12-31  2
2015-12-31  1
2016-12-31  0
2017-12-31  1
2018-12-31  1
2019-12-31  1
2020-12-31  1
```

Comment: This is tremendous thank you - I now just need to work out how to apply it to my data where there is another column called team and people can be members of more than one team :( .... SO if they are a member of 3 teams they are only counted once per year, not three times. But this is a great solution thank you